# Find the range of this function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

How do you find the range of the following function, please?

$$\frac{2x^2 + 20}{x^2 + 5}$$

Comment: Show your effort, your work about your question.

Comment: Sorry. I was in a rush. I will do so next time.

Comment: *Hint:* Rewrite your function as $2 + 10/(x^2 + 5)$. Now, what's the range of $1/(x^2 + 5)$?

Comment: Usually a question posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  This one just barely commits that offense; many others are much worse.

Comment: I apologise.  I am a beginner and need to get used to this forum.  Comments appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{2x^2+20}{x^2+5}=2+\frac{10}{x^2+5}$$
and $$0<\frac{10}{x^2+5}\le \frac{10}{0+5}= 2$$